# How to detect & count Kills/Deaths to rank players and move them between arenas?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a server and trying to make a command block that detects your kills (and if possible your Kill/Death Ratio).

Once you get 10 kills (and if possible a 25%+ K/D Ratio), You rank up to the next arena that has different kill and (if possible K/D Ratio) requirements. I'm looking for someone that can basically show me how to do this with command blocks, because all of the plugins I have tried don't do what I'm asking. If anyone can help me out I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: How much knowledge of commands do you have? What part of this do you especially need help with?

Comment: Well, all I know is to create an objective and set the players score... I need help with all of it basically.

Comment: What have you tried already? This question might attract downvotes just because you didn't show your efforts *and* the answer is somewhat easily googleable.

Comment: I have created the objectives and tried to detect how much kills a player has had but had no luck. I have tried google before this and no luck.

Comment: This is a question that should have had more research before being asked.

Answer (score 3):

Set up four objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount Deaths
/scoreboard objectives add kills playerKillCount Kills
                                 ^ OR totalKillCount if you want mob kills to count
/scoreboard objectives add kdr dummy Kill Death Ratio
/scoreboard objectives add arena dummy Arena
```

Also set up this score beforehand:

```
/scoreboard players set #1000 kdr 1000
```

And make sure every player in the first arena has `arena` = 1.

Now, run these commands on a loop:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @s kdr = @s kills
scoreboard players operation @a kdr *= #1000 kdr
execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @s kdr /= @s deaths

# Now every players' kdr score stores their kill-death-ratio,
# times 1000 so that we don't lose the fraction.

say Moving on to Arena 2: @a[score_arena_min=1,score_arena=1,score_kdr_min=250,score_kills_min=10]
scoreboard players set @a[score_arena_min=1,score_arena=1,score_kdr_min=250,score_kills_min=10] arena 2
```

And do whatever teleporting you need.

Comment: You are a life saver, my friend. Thank you so much